# 'object' in <__main__.Foo object at 0x10f43b7b8>

Tags: python, repr, python-object

Suppose a class:

```
class Foo(object): pass
```

Make an instance:

```
foo = Foo()
```

Test them in interactive mode:

```
In [80]: print(Foo)
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Good hint, class 'Foo' in first_class module `__main__`, However:

```
In [81]: print(foo)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10f43b0b8>
```

The word 'object' confuses me, why does python use `object` here instead of `instance`?

Comment: `foo` is an object. That's all. The address means that it's been located somewhere. `Foo` is a class. You'll have to get used to it, or submit a PEP.

Comment: `foo` does not inherit from `Foo`, `foo` is an instance of `Foo`, `Foo` inherits from `object`, therefore `foo` is (also) an `object`.

Comment: It make sense, a complicated logic.

Comment: Everything is an object, `<__main__.Foo object at 0x10f43b0b8>` hints nothing.

Comment: Classes are instances too so you wouldn't gain much clarity from renaming.

Comment: no idea why this question marked as opinion-based, anyone could explain it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a difference between [new-style and old-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes):

```
class Old():
    pass

class New(object):
    pass

print `Old()`
print `New()`
```

with python2.7, yields:

```
<__main__.Old instance at 0x10bc23dd0>
<__main__.New object at 0x10bc27590>
```

Initially, `repr()` on "instance" of both of old and new style class yield `<X instance at ...>`, see this [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/76e6963fc12), but later new style class instance `repr()` [changed to the current form](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ff0e6d6ef542b5b4f3c31786aa152cec68598d4f).

Answer (score -1):

A class is the collection of data and methods.

An object is an instance of a class.

Suppose you have two files: `foo.py` and `bar.py`

## Foo.py:

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

## Bar.py:

```
import Foo

class Bar:
    pass


foo = Foo.Foo()
bar = Bar()

print(foo)
# Note the parenthesis. By doing this you are making an instance.
print(Foo.Foo())
# both print something like <Foo.Foo object at 0x000000000229A128>


print(Foo.Foo)
# prints <class 'Foo.Foo'>

print(bar)
# prints <__main__.Bar object at 0x000000000229A5F8>
```

When you print either `foo` or `Foo.Foo()` (with the parenthesis) it is telling you that the instance of the class you are referencing comes from the module `Foo` and the class it references is `Foo`. Once again, the `object` part just means that it is an instance of said class coming from said module.

If you print `Foo.Foo` (without parentheses) you will just get:

```
<class 'Foo.Foo'>
```

which tells you that the class resides in module `Foo` and is named `Foo`

The same goes for printing `bar` or `Bar()` (with parenthesis):
`__main__` just means that the class you are referencing comes from the script you are currently executing.
`Bar` is the class you are referencing.

However, if you print `Bar` (No parenthesis), you will get:

```
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```

which tells us that class `Bar` resides in the main script.

## TL;DR:

`Bar` references the class `Bar()` will create an `object` or `instance` out of that class.

Hope I cleared things up.

Comment: I thought so. Were you simply wanting to make printing an object print out `<__main__.Bar instance>` instead of  `<__main__.Bar object at xxxxxxx>`?